# Text input 1px bigger than submit

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form located here: http://capeanntunaclub.com/form/index.html

The problem is that the email input box adds a 1px border to the top and bottom, in relation to the submit button. Both are set at 30px height, yet the input field shows up as 32px.

How can I fix this? I added this code to the input field, but it made no difference:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on the email input seemed to work for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

CSS's `box-sizing: border-box` is probably what you're looking for.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

*note: for Firefox there still is a vendor prefixed version `-moz-box-sizing`*

Answer (score 1):

Tuna Club...looks cool!

Seems like adding `style="height:28px;"` fixes the issue for you:

```
<input class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your Email" value="" style="height: 28px;">
```

It looks like you have some padding being added automatically to the input, so event though the button is 30px tall, the input at 28px plus padding lines up properly.

Comment: That did it! Had to change it to 28, but still. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Probably not the cleanest solution for this, however :P

Comment: @Marcel What is the drawback of using `height` vs. `box-sizing`?

Comment: the `input[type=submit]`'s box-sizing default is `border-box` while most other element's default is `content-box`.
Because of this I personally prefer adapting these to to match each other instead of using two different sizing values.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have found setting the height of form elements causes problems, let the height be auto and mess with the padding.

Also set vertical-align: baseline for both elements, it makes the bottom edge of the text for each element line up.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ofxugv0/

HTML

```
<form>
    <input class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your Email" />         
    <input class="button" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="JOIN THE CLUB" />
</form>

form {
    text-align: center;
}
```

CSS

```
#mce-EMAIL {
    font-size: 14pt;
    width: 422px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-indent: 40%;
    background-color: #75AA9F;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: 0;
    background: url(http://www.capeanntunaclub.com/form/images/catcbg2.png) repeat;
    background-color: ;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #76A9A0;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding: 7px 0 4px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
}
```